# IAM permission to retrieve LaunchTemplate's LatestVersionNumber attribute in AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, aws-auto-scaling, launch-template

While developing a CloudFormation template, I am following the principle of least privilege. So I am providing CloudFormation a role to assume, and which has the minimal set of privileges.

The template contains an `AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup` which is based on a `AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate`:

```
ECSAutoScalingGroup:
  DependsOn: ECSCluster
  Type: AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup
  Properties:
    VPCZoneIdentifier: !Ref Subnets
    LaunchTemplate:
      LaunchTemplateId: !Ref ECSLaunchTemplate
      Version: !GetAtt ECSLaunchTemplate.LatestVersionNumber
    MinSize: 1
    MaxSize: 2
    DesiredCapacity: 1
    ...

ECSLaunchTemplate:
  Type: AWS::EC2::LaunchTemplate
  Metadata:
    AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
    ...
  Properties:
    LaunchTemplateName: test-template
    LaunchTemplateData:
       ...
```

When I create a CloudFormation stack out of this template, I get the following error on the `ECSAutoScalingGroup` resource:

> Failed to retrieve attribute [LatestVersionNumber] for resource
> [ECSLaunchTemplate]: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
> (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 403; Error Code:
> UnauthorizedOperation; Request ID:
> e0f01fd0-ee2a-4260-94f4-3c65177d05ee; Proxy: null)

Which IAM policy should I add to the IAM Role which is assumed by CloudFormation? Clearly, if I give it `AdministratorAccess`, it succeeds. However, I would like to follow the principal of least privilege.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: Try ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions

Comment: @kgiannakakis yeah, I am considering ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplates also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question here. One should add these 2 actions to their IAM Role policy:

- ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplates
- ec2:DescribeLaunchTemplateVersions